# How to bind two files according to list name elements?

Tags: r, list

I have two files, one created with R which is a list which several items which looks like this :

```
$`1`
  [1] "UniRef90_A0A076JUS5"    "UniRef90_A0A076JUV9"   
  [4] "UniRef90_A0A076JUX2"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV09"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV21"   
  [7] "UniRef90_A0A076JV26"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV29"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV55"   
 [10] "UniRef90_A0A076JV60"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV80"    "UniRef90_A0A076JV85"   
 [13] "UniRef90_A0A076JV97"    "UniRef90_A0A076JVA0"    "UniRef90_A0A076JVB1"   
 [15] "UniRef90_A0A076JVE1"    "UniRef90_A0A076JVG6"    "UniRef90_A0A076JVH2"

$`2`
  [1] "UniRef90_A0A0C1REE8" "UniRef90_A0A0R2QVL5" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8VD11"
  [4] "UniRef90_A0A0T5ZPM9" "UniRef90_A0A192IQ53" "UniRef90_A0A1B1TFC1"
  [7] "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KKZ0" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KLU1" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KMN0"
 [10] "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KNT2" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KQA8" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KTM0"
 [13] "UniRef90_A0A1Z8KUR1" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8L238" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8SKE9"
 [15] "UniRef90_A0A1Z8T976" "UniRef90_A0A1Z8TG89"
```

The second one looks like :

````
>UniRef90_A0A076JUS5 - Cluster: LOW QUALITY PROTEIN: titin
MTTKAPTFTQPLQSVVALEGSAATFEAHISGSPVPEVSWYRDGQVLSAATLPGVQISFSD
GRAKLMIPAVAAGHSGRYTLQATNGSGQATSTAELLVTAETAPPNFSQRLQSTTARQGSQ
VRLDVRVTGIPTPVVKFYRDRAEIQSSPDFQILQEGDLYSLIIAEAYPEDSGTYSVNATN
SVGRATSTAELLIHGEEEAVPAKKTKTIVSTAQITQTTRQARVEKKIEAHFDARSLATSE
>UniRef90_P14198 - Cluster: AAC-rich mRNA clone AAC4 protein
MSLSNNQTQFVTVFVPIQLSIDVFRKMNNINSFVNDNLTNFPIVTVDQLIKVVNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNTSISNNGDINNCLATFEQVQNNCFETCDFKATEREHYFASGKQIQES
VLPEEEEEKISVNNFAMVTVEPNNCFVKAQQINSVAPLSLDNRNCVRRAHREVNTFVQVF
DVCVFNLKVVNVATNESQVNLFNGGNVENICFDRSIQMPRSSADDFDWSSQQQSSWYSLA
LSIIPIYHEIILVLCNWLVVAFYKYWQHQQQKQLPPHPLNIIVPNVSKRIAVNLNNQLIS```
````

I would like to know if it is possible with R , to create a new list : for each element of the first list , I would like to replace each `"UniRef90_XXXXXX"` by the value in the second file . I mean, for example,
in the first component of the list , I would like to replace :

`"UniRef90_A0A076JUS5"` by its "value" in the second file

````
GRAKLMIPAVAAGHSGRYTLQATNGSGQATSTAELLVTAETAPPNFSQRLQSTTARQGSQ
VRLDVRVTGIPTPVVKFYRDRAEIQSSPDFQILQEGDLYSLIIAEAYPEDSGTYSVNATN
SVGRATSTAELLIHGEEEAVPAKKTKTIVSTAQITQTTRQARVEKKIEAHFDARSLATSE```

Is it clear?
````

Comment: Something like this: `do.call(cbind,list(iris[1:20,],iris[21:40,],by="Species"))`? Could you add a `dput` of both files to get a better view of the aim. Hard to test without sample data.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `l2 <- l1`